# Entire "periodic" function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studing for exams and am stuck on this problem.

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function s.t. $f(z) =f(z+1)$ and $|f(z)| < e^{|z|}$.
> Show $f$ is constant.

I've deduced so far that:
a) $f$ is bounded on every horizontal strip 
b) for every bounded horizontal strip of length greater than 1 a maximum modulus must occur on a horizontal boundary.

Comment: So we need to show that $f$ is bounded and entire. We are given that it is entire. It seems that $|f(z)| < e^{|z|}$ and $|f(z+1)|< e^{|z|}$. Then $|f(z+2)| < e^{|z+1|}$.

Comment: Yes.   So as you said $f$ is bounded on horizontal strips.   I don't know how to show boundedness for the vertical strips

Comment: I think a bit of heavier machinery may be in order. You may want to estimate $\Delta\log|f|$ in the ball or radius $R$ and let $R\to\infty$. (Some familiarity with Jensen's formula may help.)

Answer (score 13):

I'm a little wary of Liouville Theorem approaches... if you choose $f(z) = {1 \over 2}\sin(2\pi z)$ then it satisfies the conditions of the problem except $|f(z)| < e^{2\pi |z|}$ instead of $|f(z)| < e^{|z|}$.

A suggestion: try showing $f(z) = g(e^{2\pi iz})$ where $g(z)$ is analytic except at $z = 0$. Then translate the condition $|f(z)| < e^{|z|}$ into growth conditions of $|g(z)|$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$ and $z \rightarrow 0$ and show that if they occur $g(z)$ must be constant.

Answer (score 4):

This is a highly non-trivial theorem in complex analysis. It is called [Carlson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson%27s_theorem). Roughly it states that if an entire function vanishes at integer points and have an exponential growth, then the function is zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Maybe you can improve this answer by adding more details. Just a friendly suggestion. Regards

Comment: Carleson's theorem is an over-kill since Carlson's theorem would allow us to replace the condition $f(z + \ell) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and all $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$, by the weaker condition $f(\ell) = f(0)$ for all $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ and obtain the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Consider 
$$
g(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{\sin(\pi z)}
$$
This is an entire function, since $\sin(\pi z)$ has poles at the integers which are cancelled by the zeros of $f(z) - f(0)$ which also occur at every integer. We have $g(z + 2\ell) = g(z)$ and also $g(x + iy) \rightarrow 0$ when $|y| \rightarrow \infty$ and $|x| \leq B$ for any fixed $B$. Therefore $g$ is bounded. Hence by Liouville $g = C$ with $C$ constant. We must have $C = 0$ because otherwise $f$ is of order greater than $e^{|z|}$ (i.e it would be of order at least $e^{|\pi z|}$). Therefore $C  = 0$ and $f(z) = f(0)$ as desired.

Comment: This proof is simply wrong. g is not bounded from what you show.

Answer (score 0):

The following lemma may help.

"If $f$ is an entire function and and $Re(f)$ is bounded, then $f$ is constant."

Write $f(z)=g(z)+ih(z)$ where $g$ and $h$ are real valued functions.  Now use the information in the question to prove that $g$ is bounded which completes the answer.

To prove the lemma consider $e^{f(z)}$ and use Liouville's theorem.

Comment: I don't see why $Re(f)$ or $Im(f)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try: Let $0<\epsilon<1$. Then

Claim: If $f$ is entire with $f(z) =f(z+1)$ such that
$$|f(z)|\leq e^{\epsilon|z|},$$
then $f$ is constant.
$(\because)$ Since $f$ is $1$-periodc, $g(z) = f\left({\log z\over 2\pi i}\right)$ is a well-defined holomorphic function except for the origin regardless of the branch cut. Check that $g(e^{2\pi iz}) = f(z)$. Then,
$$|g(z)| = \left|f\left({\log z\over 2\pi i}\right)\right|\leq \exp\left({\epsilon}\left|{\log |z|+i\arg(z)\over 2\pi i}\right|\right) = e^{\epsilon{\arg(z)\over 2\pi}}e^{\epsilon{|\log|z||\over 2\pi}}.$$
Hence, if $|z|<1$ then
$$|g(z)|\leq C |z|^{-{\epsilon\over 2\pi}}.$$
Hence,
$$|zg(z)|\leq C|z|^{1-{\epsilon\over 2\pi}}\to 0,\quad |z|\to 0.$$
Hence, $g$ can be extended analytically through the origin, i.e., $g$ is entire.
Now, if $|z|>1$ then as $|g(z)|\leq C|z|^{-{\epsilon\over 2\pi}}$ and $g$ is entire, by Cauchy inequality, $g$ is constant. Hence, $f$ is constant.

Now, letting $\epsilon\to 1$, this completes the proof.