# to show entire holomorphic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An entire function with periodic bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148027/an-entire-function-with-periodic-bounds)

$f(z)$ is an entire holomorphic function, $f(z)=f(z+1)$ and $|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|}$ then how can we show that $f$ is constant? (without using extension theorem)

Indeed this question was asked before, but is there any alternative approach?

Comment: Would you be able to explain what the Extension Theorem is?

Comment: I meant Riemann's extension theorem.

Comment: "Indeed this question was asked before:" Would you please provide a link?  If you are referring to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148027/an-entire-function-with-periodic-bounds), will you please elaborate on what you are looking for that isn't found there?