# Real-analytic $f(z)=f\left(\sqrt z\right) + f\left(-\sqrt z\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, functional-equations, analyticity

Are there nonconstant real-analytic functions $f(z)$ such that

$$ f(z)=f\left(\sqrt z\right) + f\left(-\sqrt z\right)$$

is satisfied near the real line?

Also can such functions be entire?
And/Or can they be periodic with a real period $p>0$?

Does the set of equations

$$ f(z)=f\left(\sqrt z\right) + f\left(-\sqrt z\right)$$

$$ f(z)=f(z+p)$$

$$ f ' (0) > 0$$

imply that  $f(z)= 0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \dots$, where more than $50\%$ of the nonzero signs of the $a_n$ are positive?

Related:

[Real-analytic periodic $f(z)$ that has more than 50 % of the derivatives positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839951/real-analytic-periodic-function-fz-that-has-more-than-50-of-the-derivative)

Comment: If a function is analytic and real-valued, it must be constant from the Cauchy--Riemann equations.

Comment: real-analytic means mapping the reals to some reals and being complex differentiable on an near the real line.
Your " and " interpretation seems flawed.

Comment: For instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analytic_Eisenstein_series

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mapping the reals to some reals." Do you mean that $f(\Bbb R)\subset \Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes the range is a subset of the reals.

Comment: So, $e^z$ is real-analytic? I'm sorry, I just haven't come across this term before.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Zarrax,
$$
f(z^2)=f(z)+f(-z)\tag{1}
$$
implies
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^{2k}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}z^{2k}\tag{2}
$$
therefore,
$$
a_k=2a_{2k}\tag{3}
$$
Obviously, $a_0=0$. Given $a_k$ for odd $k$, $(3)$ allows us to compute all $a_k$.

Functions with power series that satisfy $(3)$ are
$$
\begin{align}
f_n(z)
&=-\log(1-z^{2n+1})\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{k(2n+1)}}{k}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
and linear combinations of the $f_n$. Note that the $f_n$ satisfy $(1)$. In fact,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\mu(2n+1)}{2n+1}f_n(z)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(2n+1)}{2n+1}\frac{z^{k(2n+1)}}{k}\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d\text{ odd}}}\mu(d)\frac{z^n}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{2^n}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). The last equation in $(5)$ follows from
$$
\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d\text{ odd}}}\mu(d)
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if $n$ is a power of $2$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}
$$
We can use
$$
\begin{align}
f_n\left(z^{2k+1}\right)
&=-\log\left(1-z^{(2k+1)(2n+1)}\right)\\
&=f_{2kn+k+n}(z)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
to write all possible functions satisfying $(1)$ as linear combinations of the $f_n$. That is, use $(5)$ then $(7)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2k+1}\frac{z^{(2k+1)2^n}}{2^n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2k+1}\frac{\mu(2n+1)}{2n+1}f_n\left(z^{2k+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2k+1}\frac{\mu(2n+1)}{2n+1}f_{2kn+k+n}(z)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, all $f$ that satisfy $(1)$ are given by linear combinations of the $f_n$.

---

For example, we can write the example given by mjqxxxx as
$$
\log(1+z+z^2)=f_0(z)-f_1(z)
$$

Answer (score 4):

The simplest example of such a function that is real-analytic over the entire real line is
$$
f(z)=\log\left(1+z+z^2\right).
$$
We have
$$
f(\sqrt{z})+f(-\sqrt{z})=\log\left(1+\sqrt{z}+z\right)+\log\left(1-\sqrt{z}+z\right)\\=\log\left((1+z)^2-z\right)\\=\log\left(1+z+z^2\right)\\=f(z),
$$
as desired.  It's not entire, but is analytic in the neighborhood of the real line, since its branch cuts start at $z=-1/2\pm i\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: I have used your example in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/844107) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(z) = \sum_n a_nz^n$ as a power series near $z = 0$. Then the equation $f(z^2) = f(z) + f(-z)$ implies that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n z^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n + a_n (-z)^n$$
$$= \sum_{n \, even} 2a_n z^n$$
$$= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2a_{2n} z^{2n}$$
So you have to have $a_{2n} = {1 \over 2}a_n$ for all $n$. Conversely if this holds for all $n$ then the power series for $f(z)$ will satisfy $f(z^2) = f(z) + f(-z)$. So the desired equation $f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z})$ will hold for $z \geq 0$. So for example ${\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {z^{2^k} \over 2^k}}$ works. None of these functions can be made entire... if $a_n \neq 0$ then ${\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{2^{k}n}z^{2^{k}n} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{n}{z^{2^{k}n} \over 2^k}} $ diverges for $z > 1$.

I'm not sure what $f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z})$ is supposed to mean when $z$ is not a nonnegative real number. But if you fix a definition for $\sqrt{z}$ these functions will 
satisfy $f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z})$ too.

Comment: Im not yet convinced by the idea that the function cannot be made entire.
What about negative signs ?
Also : Can the function have a real period ?

Comment: Hmm it seems the radius is 1 , so not entire.
But maybe periodic after analytic continuation ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f(z)$ is an odd function $f(-z) = -f(z)$, then we obtain

$$
f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z}) = f(\sqrt{z}) - f(\sqrt{z}) = 0
$$

Note that if $f(z)$ is an even function $f(-z) = f(z)$, then we obtain

$$
f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z}) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(\sqrt{z}) = 2 f(\sqrt{z})
$$

So we look for a even function such that

$$
f(z^2) = 2 f(z)
$$

or more general

$$
f(z^n) = n f(z)
$$

The function

$$
\ln(|z|^k)
$$

has this property, so

$$
f(z) = \ln\Big(|z|^k\Big)
$$

---

Note that

$$
f\big(\pm\sqrt{-z}\big) = \ln\Big(\big|\pm\sqrt{-z}\big|^k\Big) = \ln\Big(\sqrt{|z|}^k\Big)
$$

and is well defined.

Comment: Im sorry but $f(z)=0$ is ruled out by the OP : a nonconstant function.
Also $\ln(|x|)$ is invalid : it is not real-analytic.
A logaritm is not analytic at 0.
Im aware of these ideas but they are too trivial and do not give an answer to the OP.

Comment: That is why $f(z)$ is excluded and therefore $f(z)$ MUST be an even function. That is why you can only have even powers, thus $x^2k$ or powers of $|x|$.

And $\ln(|x|)$ is real analytic - it can local be written as a power serie.

Comment: But $f(-z)$ can only be defined IF $f(z)$ contains $|z|$ in the function, thus $f(z) = g(|z|)$.

Comment: $ln(|x|)$ is not analytic at $x=0$, it does not even converge there !?

Comment: The condition

$$f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z})$$

can never be defined on $\texttt{R}$, unless we include $|z|$.

For negative values, you obtain

$$f(-z) = f(\sqrt{-z}) + f(-\sqrt{-z})$$

So this can only become 'real' IF

$$f(z) = g(|z|)$$

meaning that it is not analytical at $0$.

Comment: @mick:

From the condition follows that

$$ f(z^k) = k f(z) $$

Therefore

$$ f(0) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k f(z), 0 < z < 1$$

So $f(0) \rightarrow \pm \infty$, meaning that it is simply not analytic there...

Comment: NO , the sum of 2 complex numbers can be real, so no log like equations or absolute value equations follow from that , and still log(|x|) does not even converge for x = 0. Adding variables does not change that.

Comment: @Mick

The function $f(z)$ how you define it is not defined for $0$ as it goes to infinity.

Just consider

$$ f(0.1) $$

Then you get

$$ f(0.01) = 2 f(0.1) $$

$$ f(0.001) = 3 f(0.1) $$

$$ f(0.0001) = 4 f(0.1) $$

$$ f(0.00001) = 5 f(0.1) $$

$$ f(0.000000000000000000000\cdots) = \textrm{'}\infty f(0.1)\textrm{'} $$

Comment: Sorry but Zarrax , who gave the other answer did give a solution that was defined at $0$.
SO it seems only your log is not defined there.
AND THUS I said it was not analytic there since it did not even converge. See ?

Comment: @mick, just read it all. The function $f(z)$ is not defined at $0$ - so you cannot write it as a serie around $0$.

Comment: Sorry but Zarrax solution is defined at 0. It has a radius of 1.
In fact he ACTUALLY gave a series around 0 contrary to what you claim.

Comment: @mick, just read it all. The function $f(z)$ is not defined at $0$ - so you cannot write it as a serie around $0$.

Comment: I give up. You just said the exact same thing.

Comment: @mick, the series that Zarrax wrote is based on an assumption. But it is wrong.

As

$$
a_n = 2 a_{2n}
$$

you get

$$
a_0 = 0
$$

When you come to the conclusion that the $n$ can only be even you get

$$ f(\pm z) = a_0 + a_2 z^2 + a_4 z^4 + \cdots $$

$$ f(z^2) = a_0 + a_2 z^4 + a_4 z^8 + \cdots $$

So $a_2 = 0$, and thus $a_4 = 0$, $a_8 = 0$ and so on.

When you work it out, the serie yiels $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, i.e. $f(z) = 0$.

The serie around $0$ does not work.

Comment: The point is that a function $f(z)$ such that

$$
f(z^2) = k f(z)
$$

can never be expressed around $z=0$, for the lowest power

$$
z^k
$$

on the right side is never contained on the left side.

Comment: Hmm ok , but Your talking about function that need to be even or odd.
What if $f(z)$ is neither ?

Comment: Considering the condition you might consider another way to write $f(z)$

$$f(z) = a \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} 2^{-k} z^{2^k}$$

But this kind of sums is difficult and I wonder if there is any value for $z$ that this sum converges...

Comment: If $f(z)$ is not even nor odd, we can always write

$$ f(z) = f_\textrm{even} (z) + f_\textrm{odd}(z)$$

where

$$ f_\textrm{even} (z) = \frac{f(z) + f(-z) }{2} $$

and

$$ f_\textrm{odd} (z) = \frac{f(z) - f(-z) }{2} $$

The same properties hold and from that

$$ f_\textrm{odd} (z) = 0 $$

whence $f(z)$ can only be even.

Comment: Another way to see why you cannot write $f(z)$ around zero is that

$$ f(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) + f(-\sqrt{z})$$

But as you cannot write $\sqrt{z}$ as a serie around $0$ you cannot write $f(z)$ as a serie around $0$.

Comment: @johannesvalks You have to fix a definition of $\sqrt{z}$ for $z$ that isn't nonnegative, but once you do these power series do work. And obviously $\ln |z|$ is not real-analytic (and blows up as $z \rightarrow 0$, so there's no reason to even discuss it). Your comments have numerous errors, please stop with this.

Comment: @Zarrax and mick - you are correct!